# Disable command name autocorrection

Tags: zsh, autocorrection

I would like to disable a feature. However Zsh is ignoring the settings I am
inputting:

```
> bind
zsh: correct 'bind' to 'find' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: bind

> setopt nocorrectall
> bind
zsh: correct 'bind' to 'find' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: bind

> unsetopt correctall
> bind
zsh: correct 'bind' to 'find' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: bind
```

How are these properly used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears I was using the wrong commands. Either of these fix the issue:

```
setopt nocorrect
```

```
unsetopt correct
```